# Django - Create Images related on Article's HTML

Tags: python, django

I have an `Article` model with `html` as the text and I have an `Image` model with a field `article = ForeignKey(Article)`. If there are images added to `html` of `Article`, they should be extracted and added as objects to the `Image` model. I have written my function `create_images_from_tags` to search for `img` tags using Beautifulsoup and save them.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work and I get this error:

```
ValueError: save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'Article'.
```

Here's my `save` function of my `Article` model:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.html = self.create_images_from_tags(self.html)

    return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Placing the function after `super.save()` will end up in an endless loop, because I'd have to save the model after it again.

**EDIT**

my `create_images_from_tags` function:

```
def create_images_from_tags(self, html: str) -> str:
    """
        Creates Image objects from the HTML. Searches using Beautifulsoup for img (HTML element).
        First checks if the image already exists (using 'data-image-id' attribute on the img-tag)
            If not, an Image object will be created and the id will be saved on the tag using the `data-image-id`
            attribute.
            The img-tag 'loading' attribute will be changed to 'lazy'.

            The following attributes of the img-tags will be extracted and saved on the Image object:
                alt -> description
                data-name -> name
                src -> path (will be created to an absolute path using the BASE_DIR from the settings)
            The following static values will be saved on the Image object:
                Article -> self (the current article)
                reduced_information -> True
                from_article -> True

    :param html: Old HTML of the article
    :return: New HTML
    """
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

    for element in soup.find_all("img"):
        image_id = element.get("data-image-id", None)

        try:
            Image.objects.get(id=image_id)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            src = element["src"]
            description = element.get("alt", " ")
            name = str(element.get(
                "data-name",
                escape(f"Ein Bild vom Artikel \"{self.short_title}\"")
            ))
            # If src is relative, make full path
            if src.startswith("/"):
                path = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, src[1:]).replace("\\", "/")
            else:
                path = src

            image = Image.objects.create(
                description=description,
                name=name,

                _original=path,
                Article=self,

                reduced_information=True,
                from_article=True,
            )

            element["data-image-id"] = image.id
            element["loading"] = "lazy"
    return str(soup)
```

Comment: Why do you call `save(..)` in the `create_images_from_tags`? You should only save the `Image`s then. But with the current question regardless, it is hard to tell what is happening.

Comment: I'm not calling `save(..)` in `create_images_from_tags`. This function does only create `Image`s, but the `img` tags also get modified (an id will be added to them).

Comment: but that is, if I understand it correctly, a m2m relation? Then that will not trigger a save on the `Article` itself, but on the m2m "through" model.

Comment: Show us the `create_images_from_tags` function as well.

Comment: looks like you are trying to assign a **not saved** instance as the foreignkey, you need to save it first, then assign as the foreignkey.

Comment: You can first save your article. The `create_images_from_tags` will not trigger a new save of the `Article` object.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I know, but the returned `str` of `create_images_from_tags` is the new html of the article. How do I save this?
ps. I think we should move to a chat room, to recude the comments of this post: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a post_save signal. Process the html in your method and save it.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.html = self.create_images_from_tags(self.html)
    return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**create_images_from_tags method**

```
def create_images_from_tags(self, html: str) -> str:
   # do the processing etc to get the new html
```

**post_save signal**

```
# import your article model.
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=Article)
def create_article_images(sender, instance, **kwargs):
 soup = BeautifulSoup(instance.html, "html.parser")

 for element in soup.find_all("img"):
     image_id = element.get("data-image-id", None)
     try:
        Image.objects.get(id=image_id)
     except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        src = element["src"]
        description = element.get("alt", " ")
        name = str(element.get(
             "data-name",
                escape(f"Ein Bild vom Artikel \"{self.short_title}\"")))
            # If src is relative, make full path
        if src.startswith("/"):
            path = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, src[1:]).replace("\\", "/")
        else:
            path = src
    image = Image.objects.create(
                description=description, name=name, Article=instance,
                reduced_information=True, from_article=True,
            )
    # rest of the function ....
```

Follow this tutorial for  detail information on [How to Create Django Signals](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html)

Comment: I already found a way but I accepted your answer, so you get some extra reputation! Your way is also very good, thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

I created a method to check whether the images of the article were already created.
That's my new code now:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # If not images added yet, add them
    if not self.check_images_already_created(self.html):
        self.html = self.create_images_from_tags(self.html)
        self.save(*args, **kwargs)

    return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

def check_images_already_created(self, html: str) -> bool:
    """
        Checks whether the images of the article's HTML were already created.
    :param html: HTML of article
    :return: Whether the images were already created
    """

    # Gets ids of all images
    images_ids = set(self.images.filter(from_article=True).values_list("id", flat=True).distinct())
    found_ids = set()

    if images_ids:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

        for img in soup.find_all("img"):
            if img.has_attr("data-image-id"):
                image_id = img["data-image-id"]

                if image_id in images_ids:
                    found_ids.add(image_id)

        if images_ids == found_ids:
            return True
    return False
```

Maybe I'll help someone with this.